# Find row number of first occurrence of blank cell if conditions met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to search for the row number for the first occurrence of a blank cell if conditions are met. In the first column, it will need to find a 'T' and then in the 'Answer' column, a blank cell.

```
=MIN(IF(ExamTbl[UnLockedField]="T",IF(ExamTbl[Answer]="",ROW(ExamTbl[Answer])-ROW(ExamTbl[#Headers]),0)))
```

The formula I used just returns a 0 but in the picture, I am expecting 15 as that is the first blank cell that matches against a 'T'.

[image]

Comment: I'd use `MATCH()` with some boolean structure inside it's 2nd parameter, something like `=MATCH(1,(ExamTbl[UnLockedField]="T")*(ExamTbl[Answer]=""),0)` for ms365 user, or `=MATCH(1,INDEX((ExamTbl[UnLockedField]="T")*(ExamTbl[Answer]=""),),0)` for other versions of Excel. However, what do you want to do next when you found this row? Highlight it? Do you need to use the number somewhere?

Comment: Yes, this number will then be used in some vba code

Comment: Ok, well the answer is given to retrieve it through formula, but if it's used in VBA why not create this answer through code too? Or, if you go with formulae, consider creating the entire thing without VBA. GL.

Answer (score 0):

I have created following Excel sheet:

```
    A       B    C    D
1   H       a
2   H <BLANK>
3   H <BLANK>
4   T       b
5   T <BLANK>
6   T <BLANK>
7   H       c
8   H       d
```

In C1:C8, I've put following formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1="T",ISBLANK(B1)),1,0)
```

In D1, I've put the formula:

```
=MATCH(MAX(C1:C8),C1:C8,0)
```

In other words:

- In column "C" I put a 1 if both "A" column value is "T" and "B" column value is blank.
- In column "D" I look for the maximum value in "C" column (being 1) and ask for the first match, using exact match (hence the zero at the end).

So my sheet becomes (values):

```
    A       B    C    D
1   H       a    0    5
2   H <BLANK>    0
3   H <BLANK>    0
4   T       b    0
5   T <BLANK>    1
6   T <BLANK>    1
7   H       c    0
8   H       d    0
```

The 5 in "D1" is what you are looking for.